# What does SOSL's "Update Tracking" actually update?

Tags: knowledge, sosl

The SOSL Documenation's [Update an Article’s Keyword Tracking with SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_update_tracking.htm) page states:

> Track keywords that are used in Salesforce Knowledge article searches with the UPDATE TRACKING optional clause on a SOSL query. You can use the language attribute to search by locale.
>
> The UPDATE TRACKING clause is used to report on Salesforce Knowledge article searches and views. It allows developers to track the keywords used in Salesforce Knowledge article searches.

What does`UPDATE TRACKING` actually update, and how can we "track the keywords"?  I've looked through the Object Reference, and while the similar `UPDATE VIEWSTAT` appears to update `Knowledge__viewstat`, I can find no similar object to track keyword usage.

**Use Case:** We have had to remove the OOB "Related Articles" component because we cannot filter it; currently there are some articles which are public (no login needed), but NOT searchable (we implemented a custom site search, and we have a checkbox on `Knowledge__kav` that allows an article to be skipped in search); these articles should only be accessible to users who receive the URL directly from support.  If possible, we'd like to implement a custom "Related Articles" feed, *without* having to implement our own keyword system.  `UPDATE TRACKING` implies the possible existence of data relating articles to search terms, which could be helpful for implementing Related Articles.